# Soft question: Solutions of $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$?

Tags: calculus

Soft question:

Let $abc\neq 0$ and $$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$$ 
Besides  $$x=x_0$$
$$y=y_0$$
$$z=z_0$$
Are there any other solutions?

Comment: What do you mean. The whole point of such equation is any $(x,y,z)$ on the plane is (made) a solution. The solutions are points on the plane with normal vector $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point on the plane.

Comment: Le me get this straight: If  $2(x-3)+5(y-11)+7(z-13)=0$ then any $x,y,z$ is solution?

Comment: Any $(x,y,z)$ on the plane $P$ with normal vector $\langle 2,5,7 \rangle$ and a point $(3,11,13)$ lying on the plane is a solution. But of course not any $(x,y,z)$ is general.

Comment: Take the equation $1(x-1)+1(y-1)+1(z-1)=0$ for example and maybe take $z=0$. So now the problem becomes how many solutions to  $x+y=3$ are there. You know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a whole 2 dimensional subspace of solutions.
\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& x_0 + \frac{\lambda}{a} \\
y &=& y_0 + \frac{\mu}{b} \\
z &=& z_0 - \frac{\lambda+\mu}{c}
\end{eqnarray*}
The equation represents a plane.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! There's a whole plane of solutions, quite literally.  The equation you've given can be written as ${\bf r} \cdot {\bf n} = {\bf p} \cdot {\bf n}$, where ${\bf r} = (x, y, z)$, ${\bf n} = (a, b, c)$ and ${\bf p} = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$, which is exactly the equation of a plane. (See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html))

Answer (score 2):

Clearly so. Specify any two of $x,y,z$ arbitrarily, and then solve the simple linear equation explicitly for the third (since none of $a,b,c$ can be $0$).

Answer (score 0):

Let's perturb our proposed solution, so that $z$ changes from $z_0$ to $z_0 + \delta_z$.

Then in order to compensate the change, we need to add to $x$ and $y$ the terms $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$, such that $a\delta_x$ + $b\delta_y$ = $c\delta_z$. To parametrize this space, we need parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, both real.

Therefore the solution space is $x = x_0 + \frac{\alpha}{a}$, $y = y_0 + \frac{\beta}{b}$, and $z = z_0 - \frac{\alpha + \beta}{c}$ by inspection. This is a plane, of course.